# How to get Order Id after place order in javascript?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, php, payment-methods, knockoutjs

I am defining **placeOrder** method in my payment method, here is my code:

```
placeOrder: function (data, event) {
    var self = this;

    if (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    if (this.validate() && additionalValidators.validate()) {
        this.isPlaceOrderActionAllowed(false);

        this.getPlaceOrderDeferredObject()
            .fail(
                function () {
                    self.isPlaceOrderActionAllowed(true);
                }
            ).done(
                function () {
                    self.afterPlaceOrder();

                    if (self.redirectAfterPlaceOrder) {
                        redirectOnSuccessAction.execute();
                    }
                }
            );
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

How can I get order id before/after **afterPlaceOrder** method is called and redirection to success page is done?

Answer (score 0):

```
 as you see, add response which return orderId to done function(), code sample as below:       
     ).done(
            function (response) {
                self.afterPlaceOrder();

                if (self.redirectAfterPlaceOrder) {
                    redirectOnSuccessAction.execute();
                }
            }
        );
```